# question regarding generalized eigenvectors for Differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, generalized-eigenvector

I also have a question about the generalized eigenvector, I learned how to find the generalized vector in class, but for this practice problem, I am not sure how to find the generalized eignvectors for a 3 by 3 matrix.

[here is the image of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6Cnb.png)

My approach is the following:

Since the matrix A is upper triangular, which means the eigenvalues would just be the diagonal entries, and here we have repeated root -1 with the algebraic multiplicity of 2, and another root of 2. And I plug the eignvalue -1 and performing the row-reduced echelon form, I found the final matrix to be

\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}

and I am not sure how to go from here to find the generalized eigenvecotors, I guess my question would be how do you find the kernel and using kernel to find the generalized eigenvectors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to complicate yourself with kernels and stuff, first of all a kernel is an entity used in linear transformations. The procedure is rather straight-forward and simple :

Since $λ_1= \pm 1$ is an eigenvalue of multiplicity $2$ of the matrix $A$, what you need to do to find a generalized eigenvector is :

- Find a "common" eigenvector $v_1$, by solving the system : $(A-λ_1I)v_1=0$
- Solve the system : $(A-λ_1I)v_2=v_1$, to find the generalised eigenvector $v_2$.

The eigenvalue $λ_2=2$ is of multiplicity $1$ and does not require a generalised eigenvector.

Hope that cleared your mind a little bit, if you got any questions ask down below !

Comment: Hey thank you so much for your reply! the matrix I have found has kernel right (because it's not an identity matrix), how do you find the v1 if there is a kernel?

Comment: I can't really grasp what you mean by finding a kernel for eigenvectors. Can you elaborate ? Maybe something in the way you're expressing it is wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. what I mean is that after plugging the eigenvalue -1 in, I got the above matrix, and so the eigenvector "v1" is (0,1,-1). To find the second eigenvector, I do the same thing but the RHS would be equal to my "v1", and that would result in an augmented matrix right?

Comment: Yes ! The RHS instead of $(0,0,0)^T$ would be $v_1$ ! Sorry for the late reply. Check what I wrote you above on how to find them as well, no need to do matrix operations first of all and secondly it's more straight-forward. What you do is essentialy the same !

Comment: Thank you so much!! that makes more sense now!